# Как ускорить обработку Excel через Python? Какой модуль выбрать?

Tags: python, excel

**Задача 1**: На входе будет `10+` `Excel`-файлов с `1000+` строк в каждом файле. Программа будет находить необходимую информацию в каждом файле и создавать на основе этой информации другой файл. Другой файл будет содержать сразу все строки из тех `10`-ти файлов.

Через какой модуль реализовать быстрее? Сделал через `openpyxl` - `700` строк отфильтровались и скопировались за `10` минут. Это долго. Что можно, сделать, чтобы ускорить? Если можно, без применения асинхронности.

**Задача 2**: В тех же файлах есть строки с неявными ссылками (у ссылки есть заголовок). Как скопировать эти ссылки в другой файл? Через тот же `openpyxl` не смог это сделать. Копирует только заголовок ссылки, а саму ссылку - нет.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

poster_book = openpyxl.open('poster.xlsx', read_only=True)
poster_sheet = poster_book.active
for prop in poster_book.custom_doc_props.props:
    print(f'{prop.name}:{prop.value}')

MI_book = Workbook()
MI_sheet = MI_book.active

poster_titles = {*заголовки словаря удалены по соображениям конфиденциальности*
                  }


def write_titles_in_file():
    row = []
    for k, v in poster_titles.items():
        row.append(k)
    MI_sheet.append(row)


def get_title_links():
    poster_title_links = poster_titles.copy()
    for row_num in range(1, poster_sheet.max_row+1):
        row = poster_sheet[row_num]
        for cell in row:
            for k, v in poster_titles.items():
                if v and cell.value and v in str(cell.value):
                    poster_title_links[k] = (cell.row, cell.column)
    return poster_title_links


def get_data():
    write_titles_in_file()
    poster_data_row = poster_titles.copy()
    for row_num in range(1, poster_sheet.max_row+1):
        for k, v in poster_title_links.items():
            if v and int(v[0]) < row_num:
                cell = poster_sheet[row_num][int(v[1])-1]
                poster_data_row[k] = cell.value
        if poster_data_row['адрес'] != poster_titles['адрес']:
            write_in_file(poster_data_row)
            print(poster_data_row)


def write_in_file(poster_data_row):
    row = []
    for k, v in poster_data_row.items():
        row.append(v)
    MI_sheet.append(row)


poster_title_links = get_title_links()
get_data()
MI_book.save('MI_OOH.xlsx')
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `pandas`, в т.ч. `read_excel()` и `to_excel()`

Comment: Ссылки можно достать так https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446810/15035314

Comment: Чтобы выбрать наиболее быстрый модуль, необходимо провести сравнение разных модулей на конкретной задаче.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что можно будет ускорить. Хотите быстрее данные обрабатывать - не используйте эксель для хранения данных.

Comment: Меня одного смущает время обработки 10 минут для, условно, 10к строк? Рискну предположить что, их в экселе средствами эксель руками быстрей обработать можно. Или я что-то упустил в задаче?

Comment: Вообще код `get_data` довольно странный. Что там вообще происходит, зачем нужен цикл в цикле? Да, переменная внешнего цикла используется, но как-то очень странно используется, для одного сравнения. Всё остальное внутри этого цикла использует в основном более внешние переменные. Это не выглядит правильным. Возможно, тут то и получается квадратичная сложность вместо линейной.

Comment: Честно говоря, прежде чем обсуждать возможность дать объективный ответ или даже совет на эту тему, очень хотелось бы понять, что у Вас там за данные такие, что у Вас получилось за 10 минут обработать всего 700 строк. И получить четкое описание задачи (что имеем на входе, что хотим получить на выходе) с образцом исходников.

Comment: @АлексейР Это всё сработало, спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейР Как ни странно, но ускорило мой код также этот ответ. Заменил метод open, на метод load . Теперь те же 700 строк обрабатываются и записываются меньше, чем за минуту :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Получение ссылок**

При получении значений ячеек использовать методы hyperlink и target:

```
cell = poster_sheet[row_num][int(v[1]) - 1].hyperlink.target
```

**Ускорение программы**

При чтении файла использовать не метод open, а метод load_workbook (программа ускорилась в 10 раз):

```
poster_book = openpyxl.load_workbook('poster.xlsx')
```